# Set DateStyle to DMY On Database Migration

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

By default if the database is not created the migration will handle creation. However it will set the DateStyle to ISO, MDY. I want it to be DMY, yet I haven't found a default way to do it in `OnModelCreating` or `OnConfiguring` using Npgsql and Entity-Framework Core.

Is this possible to do in Npgsql migrations?

Comment: Can't you just issue the SQL statement `SET DateStyle = 'ISO, DMY'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateStyle isn't a database property (i.e. managed when creating the database), it's a connection parameter that simply manages how date/time values are *displayed*, i.e. converted to strings. This shouldn't affect the workings of Entity Framework Core itself in any way - EF (or rather Npgsql) reads and writes dates in binary encoding.

If for some reason you need to fetch dates as strings, you can always set DateStyle yourself as suggested by @laurenz-albe. This can be done in EFCore by simply doing `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET DateStyle = 'ISO, DMY'")` where ctx is your DbContext.